# Complex types parsing spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
Spark DataFrame Schema

root
|-- promotion-id: string (nullable = true)
|-- custom-attributes: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- custom-attribute: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- _attribute-id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- value: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

Sample Input Data

+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------- 
|_promotion-id                  |custom-attribute                                                                                                         
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------- 
|10-off-selected-appliances-wk39|[[false, geDoNotConvert,], [false, geLoyaltyPromotion,]]
|grewards_wk38_100_prize_draw   |[[,georgeClubAnswers,[Ed, Prof, Sam]]]


Sample output data

promotion_id                     geDoNotConvert  geLoyaltyPromotion  georgeClubAnswers
10-off-selected-appliances-wk39  false           false               null
grewards_wk38_100_prize_draw     null            null                [Ed, Prof, Sam]


Sample Code

val df1 = df.selectExpr("*", "inline(`custom-attributes`.`custom-attribute`)")
df1.groupBy("`_promotion-id`").pivot("_attribute-id").agg(first(col("`_VALUE`")))
```

Data - Am getting this kind of data with many additional columns in XML and am using com.databricks spark-xml_2.11 library to convert the XML data into data frame.

Requirement - Have to transform the data from array(struct) type or the column custom_attributes.custom_attribute from our example as shown in the sample output. My struct has three fields named "_VALUE", "_attribute_id", "value". I need the attribute id converted into column name with data as - check if "_VALUE" is non null, if yes, pick the data from that column. Else pick the data from "value" column. Notice that the data type of these columns might differ.

Also, I know the list of attribute id's needed.

Approach 1

As I know my attribute ID, can I iterate over the array(struct) identify the struct that has the matching attribute ID and pick the value from "_VALUE" / "value" column ?

Approach 2

Flatten the DF by using inline function and pivot the attribute ID column by fetching "_VALUE" / "value"

Questions :

Approach 1 - Can we implement it using UDF ? Any example would be helpful.

Approach 2 - What if I have multiple columns with array(struct) type ? Also, during pivot and aggr step, I need do a ternary operation on "_VALUE" / "value" column. How do we achieve it ?
Any example would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for `Approach 1`

Assuming `attribute-id` is unique with in `<custom-attributes>`

Defining Case Class - `Optional`

```
  case class Attribute(attributeId:String,_Value: String,value: Seq[String]) // Just for readable purpose.
  case class CustomAttributes(geDoNotConvert:String,geLoyaltyPromotion:String,georgeClubAnswers:Seq[String]) // Define required custom attributes
```

Defining `UDF`

```
def parseXml:UserDefinedFunction = udf((customAttribute: Seq[Row]) => {

    val attributes = customAttribute.map{row =>
      val _VALUE = row.getAs[String]("_VALUE") // extracting "_VALUE"
      val _attribute_id = row.getAs[String]("_attribute-id") // extracting "_attribute-id"
      val value = row.getAs[Seq[String]]("value") // extracting "value"
      Attribute(_attribute_id,_VALUE,value) // Wrapping above all columns into case class "CustomAttribute"
    } // Getting all attributes in to an Seq[CustomAttribute]

    val geDoNotConvert = attributes.filter(p => p.attributeId == "geDoNotConvert").headOption.map(_._Value).getOrElse(null)
    val geLoyaltyPromotion = attributes.filter(p => p.attributeId == "geLoyaltyPromotion").headOption.map(_._Value).getOrElse(null)
    val georgeClubAnswers = attributes.filter(p => p.attributeId == "georgeClubAnswers").headOption.map(_.value).getOrElse(null)

    CustomAttributes(geDoNotConvert,geLoyaltyPromotion,georgeClubAnswers) // Returning Case class
  })
```

Reading `XML` file, Parsing required columns using `UDF` & selecting columns.

```
val df =  spark.read.option("rowTag", "promotion").xml(xmlPath)
    .select($"_promotion-id",$"custom-attributes.*")
    .withColumn("customAttribute",parseXml($"custom-attribute"))
    .select("_promotion-id","customAttribute.*")
```

Printing Schema - `df.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- _promotion-id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geDoNotConvert: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geLoyaltyPromotion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- georgeClubAnswers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Final Output - `df.show(false)`

```
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------------------------+
|_promotion-id                  |geDoNotConvert|geLoyaltyPromotion|georgeClubAnswers                       |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------------------------+
|grewards_wk38_100_prize_draw   |false         |false             |[Ed Sheeran, Professor Green, Sam Smith]|
|10-off-selected-appliances-wk39|false         |false             |null                                    |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Execution Time, for two records

Approach 1 - Time taken: `4698 ms`

Approach 2 - Time taken: `8529 ms`